# How to send one parent with multi child to firebase over Google app script?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-apps-script

i have G-AppScript code where should make item batches as child of the parent "Article code" like photo below:

google sheets data table:

[image: <code>google sheets data table</code>]

the target result

[image: <code>the target result</code>]

i tried to write the link below:

*G-AppScript*

```
function writeDataToFirebase() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dataToImport = {};
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {

var ItemCode = data[i][0];
var Batch = data[i][3];

dataToImport[ ItemCode ]  = {
  ItemDesc:data[i][1],
  VenCode:data[i][8],
  VenName:data[i][9],
}

for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
  var Batch = data[i][3];
  dataToImport[ Batch ] = {
    barcode:data[i][2],
    ExpDate:data[i][4],
    ComPrice:data[i][5],
    TaxVal:data[i][6],
    PubPrice:data[i][7]
   }
  }
 }
 var firebaseUrl = "https://example.firebaseio.com/";
 var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
 base.setData("itemsInventory", dataToImport);
}
```

but i didn't get the batches as child of item code "parent"

*this is the result that i got.*

[image: the founded result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the batches to be children of the article number, you need to nest the loops,iterate over the batches for each parent and push them into a batch array inside the inner loop. Then you insert the batch array as a key-value pair into `dataToImport[ ItemCode]` - and this for every article number, inside the outer loop.

> Here is a code snippet that implements this functionality:

```
function writeDataToFirebase() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXX");
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dataToImport = {};
  var allBatches ={}; 
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    allBatches =[]; 
    var ItemCode = data[i][0];    
    for(var j = i; j < data.length; j++) {    
      var Batch = data[j][3];
      if(data[j][0]==ItemCode)
      {  
        allBatches[Batch] = {
        barcode:data[j][2],
        ExpDate:data[j][4],
        ComPrice:data[j][5],
        TaxVal:data[j][6],
        PubPrice:data[j][7]
        }
      }
     else
      {
       break;
      }   
     }
    if(ItemCode != data[i-1][0])
     {
       dataToImport[ ItemCode ]  = { 
        ItemDesc:data[i][1],
        VenCode:data[i][8],
        VenName:data[i][9],
        Batch:allBatches
       }
     }
  }

  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl("XXX")
  base.setData("", dataToImport);  
}
```

> And a screenshot of the result:

[image]

> Please note that the parameters between the brackets in the dictonaries `allBatches[Batch]` and `dataToImport[ItemCode]` must be numbers (without letters).

Comment: i swear if i'v the authority i'll give you unlimited accepting answer flags and votes
thanks again, you saved my day bro :).

Comment: But may i ask your help in little drop? I want to make batch number as child id instead of numeric serial, how can i do that?

Comment: Glad this helped you. I just found the problem about the batch number: the dictionary syntax expects for allBatches[Batch] a number as a parameter in [ ], so the code only works if you modify bn532586 to 532586 and so on. Please find the the modified code in my updated answer and make sure your badge description is a number.

Comment: i appreciate your help bro, and i'm sorry for lateness in reply
thanks again man