# Read Data from Firebase to Sheets

Tags: firebase, google-sheets

I'm having trouble splitting the data once I have retrieved it using .getData().
The firebase data is in the form:
mainTag: subTag1:"["Test1",70,0,18]", subTag2:"["Test2",65,2,18]", etc...
This is as far as I've managed to get as I'm not sure of the format of the data. I can't directly set it to the value of a single cell or a range of cells because the parameters don't match the method signature for the sheet. I've tried splitting the data as if it were an object and as if it were a string but keep getting nulls logged in the logger so I'm not sure what to do with it.

```
function getData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("TestSheet");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:D2");
  var firebaseUrl = "https://.....firebaseio.com/";
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
  var data = base.getData("mainTag");
  //range.setValues(data);
  Logger.log(data);

Logs: {subTag2=["Test2",65,2,18], subTag1=["Test1",70,0,18]}
}
```

My objective is to set the value of 4 cells in a row to the data inside each subtag. (A1="Test1", B1=70, C1=0, D1=18) Then subtag2 is in row 2 and so on. I haven't got to splitting the data yet as I'm not sure how to format the data from firebase for it to be able to be used in .setValues()

Answer (score 0):

### You need to loop through the subtags and access the values belonging to each key

This can be best achieved with [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

**Sample:**

```js
  var data = base.getData("mainTag");
  var array = [];
  for(var i in data) {
    var newdata = Object.keys(data[i]).map(function (key) { 
      return data[i][key]; 
    }); 
    array.push(newdata);    
  }
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1, array.length, array[0].length);
  range.setValues(array);
```

Comment: Using this method assigned each character in "["Test1",70,0,18]" to its own cell. eg: ", [, ", T, e, s, t, 1, ", , , 7, 0, ...

Comment: Did you convert the object manually to a string? This is usually the reason for this kind of behavior.

Comment: If you want to test it manually with test data, define `data = {subTag2:["Test2",65,2,18], subTag1:["Test1",70,0,18]}` and not `var data = '{subTag2=["Test2",65,2,18], subTag1=["Test1",70,0,18]}'`

Comment: Testing it manually works perfectly. it was converted to a string before it was written to the firebase. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Firebase data is usually as an object, not string. What is the output of `Logger.log(typeof data);`?

Comment: The logs say that it is an object. This project of mine has a read and a write component. The only way I managed to get the values from the 4 cells in sheets to be in the desired format above was to use JSON.stringify when writing the data to firebase

Comment: An object is what is to be expected and the code above works correctly for me for data retrieved from Firebase as an object. I cannot understand where your error comes from without seiing your data - I can only recommend you to implement  plenty of logs  for troubleshooting, e.g. `      Logger.log(data[i]);
      Logger.log(data[i][key]);`. For sending data to Firebase - see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57007514/how-to-send-one-parent-with-multi-child-to-firebase-over-google-app-script) helps.